# C# asp.net web api automatically creates projects with top-level statements type is there any way to avoid that?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

hello guys when I create a new asp.net core web api project, I think c# creates projects with top-level statements.Here is the freshly created web api project's program.cs file
[image]

I am new to web api projects so I am not sure if I did something unintentionally but this is what I got

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs, starting with .NET 6, the templates use top level statements. They say you should create a .NET 5 project and then manually change it to .NET 6 as a workaround if you don't want to use top level statements.

---

References:

> The C# templates for .NET 6 use top level statements.

[Tutorial: Explore ideas using top-level statements to build code as you learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements)

> While a .NET 6 console app template generates the new style of top-level statements programs, using .NET 5 doesn't. By creating a .NET 5 project, you'll receive the old program style. Then, you can edit the project file to target .NET 6 but retain the old program style for the Program.cs file.

[Use the old program style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates#use-the-old-program-style)

Comment: thank you for your answer now I have another problem.When I create a new web api projects there is only one .net framework which is .net 6 should I install .net 5 version too or is there any other way to do it

Comment: @SaitPostaci The easiest option would be to install the .NET 5 SDK

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new ASP.Net-Project via the GUI of Visual Studio, the marked Option 'Do not use top-level statements' should do what yo want.
Its in the last Step of creating a new Project:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is feature starting with c# 9.0. There is no misconfiguration in your project.

Comment: so correct me if I m wrong it is default for .net 6 framework right ?

Comment: yes. Its default behavior of dotnet 6 projects.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
dotnet new webapi --use-program-main -o <project>
```